# Server bandwidth and website weight

Tags: web-server, bandwidth, website

I was wondering...
Having the followings:

- a webserver with 100mbps output bandwidth (enough cpu and enough ram)
- a website 1 MB (Megabyte) heavy

is the following assertion true?

- The server has an output bandwidth equal to (100 (Megabit / s) / 8) = 12.5 Megabyte/s
- The web page is 1 Megabyte heavy
- Then if 13 users access the website at the same time the bandwidth run out
- Or else if 130 users access the website at the same time the webserver crash down...

(Not a fantasy situation.)

Answer (score 0):

This is correct up to the last point. The server will only be down depending on the amount of time it takes for it to catch up with all of it's clients. If a connection opens up in a ms timeframe, another client will likely have no problems connecting.

Somebody will be getting booted though.

Comment: Ops!!! Yeah I forgot: the website takes up to 3.41s (avg) to be served. Having more than 10 or 20 users within this timeframe accessing the website will likely mean a down for the server, right?

Comment: yes, thats correct.